# C++ regex cstring error

Tags: c++, regex, c-strings

I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
int compile()
{

    string linecode;
    linecode = "_hello:";

    if (std::regex_match (linecode, std::regex("(_)(.*)(:)") ))
        {

          cout<<"...";
        }
        else if (std::regex_match (linecode, std::regex("(@)(.*)(:)") ))
        {

           cout<<"@@@";
        }

return 1;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    compile();
return 0;
}
```

And i get this error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuIc8.png)

cstring error, probably in regex library.

How i can fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include <string>

Comment: i tried to include <string> but the problem still remains

Comment: you have not included <cstring>

Comment: i tried to include <cstring> but the problem still remains

Comment: Include cstring after iostream

Comment: i tried to include <cstring> after <iostream>  but the problem still remains

Comment: What's the name of that file in that screen shot? The compiler is unable to find mem*, str* functions. That's why it's not compiling

Comment: the name of  file is "main.cpp"

Comment: Not that file, the one in the screenshot which has using ::memchr etc

Comment: The name of this file is "cstring "

Comment: memchr and those str* functions are defined in  <string.h> so maybe it should work after including <string.h> after iostream

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>   i have these, but the problem still remains..

Comment: Weird, actually just including cstring should include string.h too. Looks like there's something wrong your configuration.

Comment: this program  in your pc runs?

Comment: Yup but I use Visual C++ so just copy-pasted your code and it works

Comment: hmm , the visual c++ what compiler calls? c++11 c++14 etc..

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Ok but in settings this program "visual studio" calls gcc. What std of gcc calls. For example : gcc -std =c++11